If $p(a | b)$ and $p(b)$ are Gaussian, does it imply that $p(b | a)$ or $p(a, b)$ are Gaussian too?
The title contains the whole question:
If we only know that $p(a | b)$ and $p(b)$ are Gaussian, does it imply that $p(b | a)$ or $p(a, b)$ must be Gaussian too?

Nope. $b$ could be the scale parameter for $a$.
Concretely, suppose $a|b\sim N(0,b^2)$ and $b\sim N(0,1)$.
Then $(a,b)$ has the joint distribution same as $(Z_1Z_2,Z_2)$ where $Z_1,Z_2$ are iid $N(0,1)$. In particular, $a$ marginally is the product $Z_1Z_2$ and hence non-gaussian and hence $(a,b)$ cannot be gaussian (as joint density gaussian means marginals are gaussian).
Can you compute the density of $b|a$ i.e. $Z_2|Z_1Z_2$ to conclude non-gaussianity?
